# Does NF(U+?) have $\beta$-models?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, foundations, alternative-set-theories

A $\beta$-model of a set theory (or higher-order-arithmetic theory) is a model $M$ of that theory which is *correct about well-foundedness*: if $x\in M$ is an illfounded relation, then there is some $a\in M$ which is a subset of the domain of $x$ with no minimal element.

I know a bit about $\beta$-models of ZFC- and $Z_2$-like theories - in particular, $\beta$-models of ZFC are just well-founded models of ZFC - but I've realized that embarrassingly I know nothing whatsoever about $\beta$-models of NF-like theories. The existence of a "reasonable" set theory without $\beta$-models would be amazing, so I'm sure that $(i)$ there are easy ways to construct $\beta$-models of NFU *(or even strengthenings like NFU + Infinity + Choice)* and $(ii)$ there are no major reasons to be more skeptical of the existence of a $\beta$-model of NF than of the mere consistency of NF.

That said, I still don't see how to whip them up. So:

> How does one construct a $\beta$-model of NFU?

I'm especially interested in $\beta$-models of strong extensions of NFU (like NFU + Choice + Infinity + "Cantorian sets"). I'm also interested in heuristic arguments about why *(I assume!)* the $\beta$-consistency of NF should be equiplausible with the consistency of NF.

Comment: Hopefully I can persuade Holmes or Forster to pop over and weigh in, because I would really love to know the answer to this, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no $\beta$ models of NFU.  The natural order relation on the ordinals of NFU in a given model M is ill-founded, externally, but M thinks it is well-founded.  So there are collections of ordinals of M which have no minimal element, but none of these are sets of the model M.  This is a classic result:  there is a paper about it, to which I should supply a reference when I am not on vacation away from my office.

Answer (score 4):

(Thank you, Alice, for getting me to look at this) Before i answer i think i need a bit of clarification on what exactly a $\beta$-model is.  On the face of it NFU cannot have a model which speaks about wellfoundedness without forked tongue, beco's the ordinals of any model of NF(U) are illfounded.  That is to say, it is a theorem of NF(U) that there is (an explicitly definable) proper class of ordinals with no least member.  (It may be that Rosser-Wang ``Nonstandard models for formal logics'' addresses your interests .. JSL some time early 1950's - they discuss NF in some detail)   But it may be that you mean something subtly different.

```
  best wishes

     tf
```

Comment: I think i can express my concern more specifically:  i need to be told the difference between a $\beta$-model and an $\omega$-model.  It is known since at least Rosser-and-Wang that the Quine systems have no $\omega$-models.

Comment: @ThomasForster An $\omega$-model has its $\omega$ isomorphic to the usual $\omega$. To see the difference between this and $\beta$-model-ness, note that there are $\omega$-models of ZFC which are not $\beta$-models: e.g. via Gandy's basis theorem we can build a model of ZFC with well-founded part of height $\omega_1^{CK}$.

Comment: The definition of well-founded I'm using is the one given in my question, which seems self-contained unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Also, Randall Holmes' answer below states "The natural order relation on the ordinals of NFU in a given model M is ill-founded, externally, but M thinks it is well-founded," which seems to contradict your statement " it is a theorem of NF(U) that there is (an explicitly definable) proper class of ordinals with no least member" - am I missing something, or is one statement in error?

Comment: And I'm confused by your claim that NFU has no $\omega$-models; it seems to me that if we run the Jensen construction starting with an $\omega$-model of ZFC with an automorphism $j$ (which necessarily moves an ordinal), we get an $\omega$-model of NFU?

Comment: Yes, *I* need to be more precise too.  NFU (and quite possibly NF too) has models in which the natural numbers of the model are isomorphic to the  natural numbers according to the enveloping theory.   However every model of NF(U) contains things which it believes to be wellorderings but which can be seen from outside not to be.   I'm afraid i still don't understand what a $\beta$ model is.  Can i trouble you to break it up small for me?

Comment: Noah:  you write: 

    You write "The natural order relation on the ordinals of NFU in a given model M is ill-founded, externally, but M thinks it is well-founded," which seems to contradict Thomas Forster's statement that "it is a theorem of NF(U) that there is (an explicitly definable) proper class of ordinals with no least member" - am I missing something, or is one statement in error? – Noah Schweber 21 mins ago

Randall and i are in complete agreement, but the ration of characters means i have no space to provide the clarification.  Please supply an email addr so i can reply offline

Comment: @ThomasForster My email is schweber [at] berkeley [dot] edu.

Comment: @ThomasForster "NFU (and quite possibly NF too) has models in which the natural numbers of the model are isomorphic to the natural numbers according to the enveloping theory." Those would be $\omega$-models. "every model of NF(U) contains things which it believes to be wellorderings but which can be seen from outside not to be." Those would be non-$\beta$ models. A $\beta$-model is just any model $M$ such that, whenever $x\in M$ and $R\in M$ is a binary relation on $x$ (according to one's favorite pairing notion) such that *externally* there is some subset of $x$ with no $R$-minimal element,

Comment: then there is such a subset of $x$ in $M$ already.

Comment: The assertion that Thomas makes that there is a proper class of ordinals which has no minimal member isn't in conflict with my assertion that a model M of NFU thinks that its ordinals are well-ordered when in fact that are not:  in fact what Forster says is essentially the same thing as what I am saying in other words.

Comment: Further remark:  NFU definitely has omega-models (in which the natural numbers are standard).  What it does not have is countably complete models, in which every countable subcollection of the model is a set.  Every model of NFU contains a decreasing sequence of ordinals (indexable externally by natural numbers);  NFU fails to be honest about well-foundedness quite badly.

Comment: In connection with the conflict Noah seems to perceive between my assertion about ordinals and Thomas's, it is useful to note that in NFU a definable subclass of a set may fail to be a set.