# Does NF(U+?) have "$\beta$ish-models"?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, foundations, alternative-set-theories

A $\beta$-model of an appropriate theory (= something rich enough to talk about sets in a reasonable way) is a model of that theory such that every relation in the model which is *externally* ill-founded is *internally* ill-founded. For example, $\beta$-models of ZFC are precisely the well-founded models, while $\beta$-models of theories of second-order arithmetic are quite important in reverse mathematics.

It turns out that [Quine-style set theories do not have $\beta$-models](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3508314/28111). However, that particular argument does not immediately rule out a kind of "weak correctness" property:

> Say that $M\models NFU$ is a *$\beta$ish-model* if whenever $r\in M$ is some externally ill-founded relation on some $x\in M$, there is a *$M$-definable class* $A\subseteq M$ such that $A\subseteq x$ and $A$ has no $R$-minimal element.

So, for example, the ordinals in an $\omega$-model $M$ of NFU do *not* immediately constitute a counterexample to $\beta$ish-model-ness since there is an $M$-definable class of ordinals with no least element. For things like ZFC and second-order arithmetic, "$\beta$ish" isn't a distinct notion, but for Quine-style theories that's not clear to me.

My question is:

> Is it consistent with our current knowledge that there are $\beta$ish models of any of the usual Quine-style set theories *(in particular, NFU, NF, NFU + Infinity + Choice)*?

---

There's a third notion of "correctness for wellfoundedness" - namely, for every externally illfounded **class** relation in the model there is a class in the model with no minimal element. At a glance this property ("$\beta$ish$^+$?") seems potentially different from both $\beta$- and $\beta$ish-ness, and it might actually be the "right" property to consider. But the above seems more manageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer this question positively modulo an assumption whose consistency strength I do not know. Roughly speaking, I need a $\beta$-model of $\mathsf{KP}(\mathcal{P})+$"there exists a Reinhardt cardinal". All I know is that the existence of a rank-into-rank cardinal (or an actual Reinhardt, since this construction can be done on the level of definable classes) is good enough. It's likely that somebody who knows more would be able to sharpen this result.

---

What I need precisely is that there exists a transitive set $M$ such that

- $M$ satisfies adjunction (i.e., for any sets $x,y \in M$, the set $x \cup \{y\}$ is in $M$),
- $M$ satisfies $\Delta_0$-comprehension,
- $M$ is a $\beta$-model (i.e., any internally well-founded set relation is externally well-founded),
- the ordinal rank functions on well-founded relations and on sets are definable in $M$,
- for every ordinal $\alpha \in M$, the set $V_\alpha^M$ of all sets in $M$ of rank less than $\alpha$ is an element of $M$, and
- there is a proper elementary self-embedding $f : M \prec M$ with critical point $\alpha$ (i.e., $f$ moves some rank up, and $\alpha$ is the smallest ordinal in $M$ such that $f(\alpha) > \alpha$).

Note that for any set $x \in M$, the Cartesian product $x \times x$ is an element of $M$. This is the standard argument that powerset and comprehension are enough to get the existence of Cartesian products. We need adjunction to make sure that Kuratowski ordered pairs exist and to ensure that the height of $M$ is a limit ordinal.

Given $f$, construct a sequence of structures $(N_i)_{i<\omega}$ by setting $N_0 = M$ and choosing each $N_{i+1}$ so that $(N_{i+1},N_i)\cong (M,f(M))$. Let $N = \bigcup_{i<\omega}N_i$. Clearly we have that $N \equiv M$.

$f$ induces an automorphism $j$ on $N$ defined by sending each element $a$ of $N_i\cong M$ to the element corresponding to $f^{-1}(a)$ in $N_{i+1}$. Now we have that $\alpha \in N$ is an ordinal rank with $j(\alpha) < \alpha$, so we can apply the Boffa construction of a model of $\mathsf{NFU}$, i.e., we build a structure $A$ whose underlying set is $V_\alpha^N$ with an element-of relation $x\in^\ast y$ which holds if and only if $j(x) \in y\wedge y \in V_{j(\alpha)+1}^{N}$.

$\Delta_0$-comprehension is all that we need to ensure that this structure is a model of $\mathsf{NFU}$. [By a result of Holmes](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-53/issue-4/The-Usual-Model-Construction-for-NFU-Preserves-Information/10.1215/00294527-1722764.full), $\in$ and the restriction of $j$ to $V_\alpha$ are definable in $A$. (All that this argument needs is that the set $E=\{(\{x\},x): x \in j(V_\alpha^N)\}$ is in $N$, which ensures that $j^3(E)$ is in $V_{j(\alpha)+1}^N$. This follows from the earlier remark regarding Cartesian products.)

Now we need to relate binary relation that $A$ thinks are well-founded to binary relations that $N$ thinks are well-founded. Let $r \in V_\alpha^N$ be a binary relation on some set $x\in V_\alpha^N$. Since $\in^\ast$ and $\in$ agree on the subset relation and on what Kuratowski ordered pairs are, we have that $A\models$"$r$ is well-founded" if and only if $N \models$"$r$ is well-founded". (Note though that $\in^\ast$ and $\in$ disagree about what the *elements* of $x$ are, but this doesn't actually matter.)

We will also need the following claims.

> *Claim 1.* If $\gamma \in N$ is an (internal) ordinal such that for all $\delta \leq \gamma$, $j(\delta)=\delta$, then $(\gamma, <)$ is (externally) well-founded.

*Proof.* This follows immediately from the fact that any element of $N$ fixed by $j$ must be an element of $N_0\cong M$, which is well-founded. $\square_{\text{claim}}$

> *Claim 2.* If $r \in N$ is a binary relation on some set $x \in N$, then $(x,r)$ is externally ill-founded if and only if either $N \models$"$r$ is ill-founded" or there is some $b \in x$ such that $N \models j(\mathrm{rk}(b)) < \mathrm{rk}(b)$.

*Proof.* If $N \models r\text{ is ill-founded}$, then clearly $(x,r)$ is externally ill-founded. If there is some $b \in x$ such that $N \models j(\mathrm{rk}(b)) < \mathrm{rk}(b)$, then $r$ has a rank function with values in an ill-founded ordinal. Since the theory of $M$ (and therefore also the theory of $N$) knows that the set of ranks occuring in $(x,r)$ is an initial segment of the ordinals, we have that $(x,r)$ is externally ill-founded.

Now suppose that $N \models r\text{ is well-founded}$ and for every $b \in x$, $j(\mathrm{rk}(b))=\mathrm{rk}(b)$. By Claim 1, we have that $(x,r)$ has a rank function with values in a well-founded ordinal, wherefore $(x,r)$ itself is well-founded. $\square_{\text{claim}}$

So for any $x,r \in A$ (i.e., in $V_\alpha^N$) with $r$ an externally ill-founded binary relation on $x$, either $A \models$"$r$ is ill-founded", in which case this is witnessed by some set in $A$, or we can consider the sub-class
$$\{y \in x : (\exists \gamma \leq \mathrm{rk}(y))j(\gamma) < \gamma\}$$
which contains no $r$-minimal element and so witnesses that $r$ is externally ill-founded. So we have that $A$ is a $\beta$ish-model of $\mathsf{NFU}$.

---

I don't know whether $A$ satisfies the stronger version of the $\beta$ish-model condition that you mentioned. At its face, it seems like it might at best have it for "$\in$-$\Delta_0$-definable" classes.

By strengthening the theory of $M$ you can strengthen the resulting theory of $A$. Since the automorphism $j$ can't touch $\omega$, the requirements I've written imply that $M$ satisfies the (von Neumann ordinal) axiom of infinity, so $A$ will also satisfy the (Frege cardinal) axiom of infinity. ($\mathsf{NFU}+\neg\mathrm{Inf}$ implies that every set is Dedekind finite. Whatever $\omega$ turns into will not be Dedekind finite. Amusingly, I can't actually see a way to construct a $\beta$ish-model of $\mathsf{NFU}+\neg\mathrm{Inf}$.) $A$ should also satisfy the axiom of counting (i.e., that the set of finite cardinals is strongly Cantorian).

<s>As for</s> $\mathsf{NF}$ <s>itself, Holmes's (tentative) proof that</s> $\mathsf{NF}$ <s>is consistent is a compactness argument, and to me there's no clear way to modify it to control well-foundedness of parts of the resulting model.</s> EDIT: See the discussion in the comments.

Comment: Wow, I haven't thought about this in a while. It will take me some time to read through this answer!

Comment: @NoahSchweber I probably should have written it starting from a rank-into-rank cardinal and then summarized what you actually need at the end. If it makes it easier, just think of $M$ as some $V_\kappa$ that has a non-trivial elementary self-embedding. I think that this might also get you the stronger condition you were thinking about.

Comment: Is Randall's proof (of Con(NF)) a compactness argument? I was under the impression it was more complicated than that. That a tangled web, if I remember my terms correctly, provides you directly with a model of NF.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Perhaps I should be a bit more careful with my statement. I only really understand the easy part of the proof that goes from a model of tangled type theory to a model of $\mathsf{NF}$, which is definitely a compactness argument. Are you saying that the full proof goes around this somehow?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that I'm not sure that tangled web to NF is a compactness argument per se, especially not with the construction of Randall where we build this nice tree directly. I think that you can directly interpret TST into the Specker tree.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay I think I didn't read carefully enough. I thought that the argument actually went through tangled type theory, but I think I see now that it doesn't. I want to make sure I understand this part though: The proof that $\mathsf{NF}$ is consistent from the consistency of tangled type theory *is* a compactness argument, right?

Comment: @James: I don't know, I'm not the expert for that. If I could superping, Malice Vidrine is the right person for this question (on this site).

Comment: @AsafKaragila The argument use Ramsey's theorem to show that every finite part of typical ambiguity is consistent with $\mathsf{TST}$.

Comment: Let $(x,r)$ be $(\alpha + 1,\in)$ in $M\subset N$; this is externally well-founded, but it is not the case that $N\vDash j(rk(\alpha)) = rk(\alpha)$, because $rk(\alpha)$ does not exist. So I don't find it obvious that this $A$ is $\beta$-ish.

Comment: @BenStandeven I might not be understanding what you're saying, but I don't believe this is an issue. $N$'s copy of $(x,r)$ is not externally well-founded because it contains the infinite descending sequence $\alpha, j(\alpha), j(j(\alpha)), \dots$. On the other hand, $M$'s copy of $(x,r)$ isn't going to be isomorphic as a binary relation to any pair $(y,s)$ in $N$.